# How to correctly fit Cox Regression with coxphf? (Firth’s penalized maximum likelihood bias reduction method in R)

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, multivariate-testing

I am trying to fit a Cox regression (package needed:survival), and have run into a problem. When I try to fit a "regular" Cox regression model with my data, I receive the error message "X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 9" (and if I remove variable 9, the problem becomes variable 8). As far as I understand the problem, this happens because too many patients with these variables have the same event (I believe in another question this was called "perfect classification")

That's why I tried to fit a Cox model with coxphf function (package of the same name), as this should take care of the problem by using "Firth’s penalized maximum likelihood bias reduction method" for the Cox regression. But this also doesn't seem to work, until I increase the "maxit" from the default 50 to 1000 and remove the "undefined" variable from the equation. But if I remove the undefined variable from my dataset (it is only 1 person), the model doesn't seem to work again.

So my question is, how can I solve this? Is it even appropriate/necessary to remove the whole variable (a therefore that 1 person) from the dataset?  Probably made some very obvious mistakes, but please bear with me, since I have absolutely no background in statistics. Thank you very much already in advance.

I included the following sample data, as well as my attempts to fit the Cox model.
So this is how I managed to get the model to work, by leaving out the "Undefined" variable from the model:

```
# load packages
library("survival")
library ("coxphf")

example<-structure(list(Pat.nr. = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
67L, 68L, 69L), OS = c(1.6, 34.6, 1.5, 35.8, 7.7, 38.6, 37.6, 
8.6, 0.6, 5.7, 0.6, 43.9, 25.8, 7.3, 28.1, 43.8, 12.8, 18.5, 
36.1, 43.1, 15.4, 37.6, 8.6, 2.7, 10.2, 8.1, 37.3, 25.3, 3.7, 
26.1, 41.2, 5.9, 15.5, 56.8, 29.5, 52.1, 5.4, 54.8, 53.5, 16.6, 
49.2, 53.8, 8.5, 56, 7.4, 28, 3.3, 38, 55.7, 0.4), Event = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L), Age = c(68.41, 54.9, 44.44, 64.14, 68.86, 62.93, 40.76, 
31.06, 42.97, 69.16, 47.39, 60.14, 27.9, 56.57, 19.63, 47.75, 
45.58, 66.22, 43.73, 45.34, 38.83, 54.46, 48.91, 70.3, 60.51, 
68.55, 63.18, 55.89, 68.27, 57.25, 56.17, 60.83, 74.42, 71.3, 
40.36, 50.85, 59.61, 50.14, 45.77, 19.34, 56.32, 53.38, 70.7, 
55.25, 56.05, 44.06, 51.36, 69.37, 69.71, 75.44), Favorable = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L), Intermediate = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), Adverse = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Undefined = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("Pat.nr.", "OS", "Event", "Age", "Favorable", 
"Intermediate", "Adverse", "Undefined"), row.names = c(NA, 50L
), class = "data.frame")


#row&columns
n_row <- dim(example)[1]
n_col <- dim(example)[2]

#variables:
OS <- c(example[1:n_row,2])
Event <- c(example[1:n_row,3])
age <- c(example[1:n_row,4])
Favorable <- c(example[1:n_row,5])
Intermediate <-  c(example[1:n_row,6])
Adverse <- c(example[1:n_row,7])
Undefined <-  c(example[1:n_row,8])


# dependent and independent variables
y <- Surv(OS, Event)
x <- cbind(age, Favorable, Intermediate, Adverse, Undefined)  
example <- data.frame(cbind(x,y)) 

#coxphf with Firth's Penalized Likelihood --> which doesn't seem to work
cox2<-coxphf(data=example,y~x, firth=TRUE, pl=TRUE, maxit=1000)
summary(cox2)

#coxphf with Firth's Penalized Likelihood (without Variable "Undefined") --> this works
cox2<-coxphf(data=example,y~age+Favorable+Intermediate+Adverse, firth=TRUE, pl=TRUE, maxit=1000)
summary(cox2)
```

And here, I have modified the dataset to not include the undefined variable (and the model doesn't work anymore):

```
example1<-structure(list(Pat.nr. = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 72L), OS = c(1.6, 34.6, 1.5, 35.8, 7.7, 38.6, 37.6, 
8.6, 0.6, 5.7, 43.9, 25.8, 7.3, 28.1, 43.8, 12.8, 18.5, 36.1, 
43.1, 15.4, 37.6, 8.6, 2.7, 10.2, 8.1, 37.3, 25.3, 3.7, 26.1, 
41.2, 5.9, 15.5, 56.8, 29.5, 52.1, 5.4, 54.8, 53.5, 16.6, 49.2, 
53.8, 8.5, 56, 7.4, 28, 3.3, 38, 55.7, 0.4, 2.8), Event = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Age = c(68.41, 54.9, 44.44, 64.14, 68.86, 62.93, 40.76, 
31.06, 42.97, 69.16, 60.14, 27.9, 56.57, 19.63, 47.75, 45.58, 
66.22, 43.73, 45.34, 38.83, 54.46, 48.91, 70.3, 60.51, 68.55, 
63.18, 55.89, 68.27, 57.25, 56.17, 60.83, 74.42, 71.3, 40.36, 
50.85, 59.61, 50.14, 45.77, 19.34, 56.32, 53.38, 70.7, 55.25, 
56.05, 44.06, 51.36, 69.37, 69.71, 75.44, 71.05), Favorable = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), Intermediate = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L), Adverse = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Pat.nr.", 
"OS", "Event", "Age", "Favorable", "Intermediate", "Adverse"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")

#row&columns
n_row <- dim(example1)[1]
n_col <- dim(example1)[2]

#variables:
OS <- c(example1[1:n_row,2])
Event <- c(example1[1:n_row,3])
age <- c(example1[1:n_row,4])
Favorable <- c(example1[1:n_row,5])
Intermediate <-  c(example1[1:n_row,6])
Adverse <- c(example1[1:n_row,7])




# dependent and independent variables
y <- Surv(OS, Event)
x <- cbind(age, Favorable, Intermediate, Adverse)  
example <- data.frame(cbind(x,y)) 

# dependent and independent variables
y <- Surv(OS, Event)
x <- cbind(age, Favorable, Intermediate, Adverse)  
example1 <- data.frame(cbind(x,y)) 

#coxphf with Firth's Penalized Likelihood

cox2<-coxphf(data=example,y~x, firth=TRUE, pl=TRUE, maxit=1000)
summary(cox2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I went about a tiny bit different with your data and did not have any problems. First of all, I excluded the `Undefined` column, as a variable without any variation does nothing for your model (and will create errors).

Then, I just bound your `Surv()` object to the data you provided:

```
example$survive <- Surv(time = OS, event = Event)
```

and called the `coxphf()` with default settings (as `firth` and `pl` are `TRUE` by default), not changing the default iteration of 50, and used the correct formula specification:

```
cox2 <- coxphf(survive ~ Age + Favorable + Intermediate + Adverse, data = example)

> summary(cox2)
coxphf(formula = survive ~ Age + Favorable + Intermediate + Adverse, 
    data = example)

Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood 

                     coef   se(coef)  exp(coef)  lower 0.95 upper 0.95     Chisq          p
Age           0.005652315 0.01598045 1.00566832 0.976272961  1.0391381 0.1297188 0.71872373
Favorable    -3.335329337 1.25086821 0.03560286 0.004236556  0.4169422 6.3231629 0.01191709
Intermediate -1.672995547 0.61363779 0.18768401 0.066460220  0.6321023 6.4756709 0.01093610
Adverse      -3.412597661 1.25225958 0.03295548 0.003909284  0.3863706 6.4164893 0.01130655

Likelihood ratio test=6.535659 on 4 df, p=0.1625574, n=50
Wald test = 7.794526 on 4 df, p = 0.09940164

Covariance-Matrix:
                       Age   Favorable Intermediate      Adverse
Age           0.0002553747 -0.00220437 -0.001027825 -0.001760528
Favorable    -0.0022043699  1.56467129  0.710597909  1.408715695
Intermediate -0.0010278246  0.71059791  0.376551335  0.705180703
Adverse      -0.0017605280  1.40871570  0.705180703  1.568154050
```

Can I ask why the `Intermediate` column has values set to 2 instead of 1? Isn't it just a binary indicator of a categorical variable?

Comment: Thank you!
Yes of course you can ask, I made a mistake while constructing the sample data set (as I separated the risk groups, which were previously summarized in 1 variable).
So technically it is ok to just exclude the variable from the model without changing the data set? (This doesn't create any errors, since there will be one person who doesnt belong to any of the 3 remaining risk categories?)
And what does binding the Surv() object to the data exactly do?

Comment: Binding the object to the data lets you use the correct `formula, data` input format of the `coxphf` function. You could try excluding the one case without any observation on one of the three variables to see if there's a difference in the results. Generally, this is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.
In the second example (dataset: example1) I tried to exclude that one case without any observations on the 3 variables from the model, but then that didn't work anymore.
What would be more correct: to exlude the case where there were no observations or to leave it in the model? 
And why doesn't the model seem to work anymore when I exclude it?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why that error occurs. This may be a problem of the package itself. The github commenting does not really clarify this [link to Github of coxphf](https://github.com/cran/coxphf/blob/master/R/coxphf.R).

Comment: Thank you for all your help. If you don't mind me asking, what would you recommend doing?

Comment: Do you have any qualitative information about the `Undefined` case? Would it be possible to recode it into one of the other categories? If not, I would run the regression on the whole dataset and exclude the `Undefined` variable. It should not make a difference.

Comment: Ok, thank you! In that case I will run it as a whole and exclude the Undefined variable. Unfortunately I can't recode it, since the classification is based on genetic markers and that particular person didn't have any cytogenetic analysis.

Comment: The error message is quite baffling. I cannot find any structure in your data that would make this specific case necessary for any kind of computation. As soon as you change anything, even setting the value of `Favorable` to 1 for this case and then leaving it in, the `coxphf` won't work anymore.

Comment: That is very strange indeed. Maybe I should try to find another way to fit the Cox model. Just in case there is an error in the package itself?
Would you have an idea for another method?

Comment: Do you have more explanatory variables you could include in the regular Cox model to account for the perfect classification? Right now you are predicting on age and the genetic marker variable alone, which might be a bit thin.

Comment: The whole model contains some molecular and genetic markers as well as gender and white blood cell count. However, since they all don't cause the problem I took them out, to simplify the example in the question. The cohort unfortunately only consists of 103 patients, so I think the perfect classification is accounted by a small sample bias.

Comment: You could ask another question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) to get more input on the method and your model.